# Having problems with my linear search random number generator

Tags: python

I have no clue why this doesn't work, it's a random number generator from 1-100 which generates 50 numbers then asks for user input to see if that number is contained in the list. I don't see why this is a syntax error:

[image]

Comment: Could you please put your code as properly formatted Python text directly into the question? Not an image. Thank you

Comment: Indentation matters in Python, the `else` is not connected to the `if`.

Comment: Your issue is simply formatting, make sure lines 15 and 16 are properly indented.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indent correctly. Instead of:

```
if num in mylist:
    print("The list is:", mylist)
position = LinearSearch(mylist, num)
print("element", 'num, is at position', position)

else:
    print("Your number was not in the list ;-;")
```

You want:

```
if num in mylist:
    print("The list is:", mylist)
    position = LinearSearch(mylist, num) #notice the indention
    print("element", 'num, is at position', position) #notice the indention

else:
    print("Your number was not in the list ;-;"
```

This tells python that the `else` goes with the `if` since the other lines are not "in between" them.